# GTK3 theme in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gtk3, kde4

I am using Kubuntu 12.04 and QtCurve widget style which does not support GTK3:

[image]

How can apply a GNOME theme for GTK3 apps?

I found an advice [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116451): installed `gnome-themes-standard` and `gnome-themes-extras` packages, created file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = Adwaita
gtk-fallback-icon-theme = gnome
```

But this didn't help.

Comment: Do you see any other options in *GTK+ Appearance – KDE Control Module*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a great tool that let's you easily configure GTK2 and GTK3 themes on KDE:

## GTK2 + GTK3 Configuration under KDE

[Archlinux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=kde-gtk-config)
[Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/kde-config-gtk-style)

Go to the place where you downloaded your file and in a console type:

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

Where package name is the name of the package you downloaded

If it complains about a ependeny kdebase-runtime needed, simply install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install kdebase-runtime
```

On KDE System Settings - Applications Appearance you now have more 2 menus on the left tab, where you can choose GTK2 or GTK3 themes

[image]

Source: https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/base/kde-gtk-config

Comment: I installed the package, the GTK2 theme works ok, but the GTK3 theme is not changing, whatever theme for it i select: http://imgur.com/zsEro Even oxygen-gtk

Comment: You may also find usefull installing these addons :`sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen  kde-config-gtk oxygen-molecule`

Comment: I have these installed - still the same

Comment: Try removing that settings.ini file you have altered and then setting a new GTK3 theme

Comment: sorry, doesn't help

Comment: Recreate the file settings.ini, but choose `gtk-theme-name=oxygen-gtk` restart KDE

Comment: At home, where i use Kubuntu 12.10, everything is fine. So i accept your answer and will try to set up settings on my another machine.

Comment: The solution i posted here, is the one i always do on my computers, I always install Ubuntu, and later i install KDE, having that problem of the appearance of GTK aplications in KDE. I run this procedure and everything is fine.

Comment: I also haven't had any problems until GTK3 apps appeared, as QtCurve doesn't suppor GTK3

Comment: good job man, but that is one ugly theme :D

Comment: i confirm that gtk3 theme won't change too

Comment: I uninstalled gtk3-engines-oxygen, relogged (or restart), and now changing gtk3 theme work.