# How to work around Eclipse Luna/GTK bug 339174 (change to not use oxygen)

Tags: 12.04, themes, eclipse, gtk

The bug is described here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339174
For me it fails with:

```
java: /build/buildd/oxygen-gtk3-1.0.2/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Assertion `!_button._widget' failed.
```

Problem is if I go to GTK+ Apperance in Control Module and change to anything other than oxygen Eclipse will look totally awful.

Regardless what theme I use (tried QtCurve and Raleigh) it has the same look with huge padding around all controls etc.

Is it possible to have a sensible look without oxygen GTK?

I have kubuntu-desktop installed over the stock LTS distro.

```
 $dpkg -l libgtk* | grep -e '^i' | grep -e 'libgtk-*[0-9]'
    ii  libgtk-3-0                             3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8                          GTK+ graphical user interface library
    ii  libgtk-3-bin                           3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8                          programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
    ii  libgtk-3-common                        3.4.2-0ubuntu0.8                          common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
    ii  libgtk2.0-0                            2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1                        GTK+ graphical user interface library
    ii  libgtk2.0-bin                          2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1                        programs for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
    ii  libgtk2.0-common                       2.24.10-0ubuntu6.1                        common files for the GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found two solutions:

- [disable GTK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542883/eclipse-4-4-luna-ugly-theme-with-xfce-4-11) by exporting `SWT_GTK3=0`, then change the GTK2 theme to something else than oxygen (e.g QtCurve). Without the second step oxygen-gtk2 will crash eclipse too.
- [change GTK3 theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179322/gtk3-theme-in-kde/179341#179341) - I was unable to change it with the GUI tools provided with KDE. I had to install `kde-gtk-config` and remove `settings.ini` in `~/.config`

Comment: the 'SWT_GTK3=0' trick didn't work for me, and nor did I (quickly enough) figure out how to install 'kde-gtk-config', however, using 'GTK+ Appearance' I was able to change the theme away from Oxygen (labeled 'Widget style' in the GUI), and that worked! thx

Comment: @MattS. how did the SWT_GTK3=0 "didn't work"? Was it still crashing or was the look the same?

Comment: @Bochenski, was still crashing. More precisely, eclipse would load, but on going into a specific dialog (preferences --->  Java Editor --> Syntax Coloring) eclipse would still hard crash.

Comment: @MattS. apparently there are bugs both in oxygen-gtk2 and -gtk3, see the updated anwser

Comment: SWT_GTK3=0 worked for me for ubuntu 14.04 and eclipse mars. Thanks!!!